# Sencha Touch 1.1 : How do I get individual list record without tapping on list?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I have a list of items and I have inserted  toggle button in my list. Now depending on the value of `active` in the store I am trying to set the value of toggle button.

The problem I am facing is I don't know how to get list's record without tapping or selecting it.

Here is the code ..

```
   var itemTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate (
       '<tpl for = ".">',
            '<div>{name}</div>',
            '<div class= "subSectionToggleButton"></div>',    
        '</tpl>'
    );


    var subSectionList = {
        height: 350,
        id: 'sList',
        xtype: 'list',
        store: App.stores.subSections,
        grouped: true,
        itemTpl: itemTemplate, //Don't need to worry about this
        listeners: {
            'refresh' : function (e) {
    //insert toggle button in empty div class inside template   
                e.getEl().select('div .subSectionToggleButton').each(function(item) {
                    var toggleButton = new Ext.form.Toggle ({
                       renderTo: item,
                       listeners : {
            // After render I want to get the individual record, read whether it is active or not.. and then do setValue(value) on toggle button
                           'afterrender' : function (f) {
                               var rec = Ext.getCmp('sList').getRecord(f);
                                console.log(rec); // I get undefined here

                // I know how to get a record when you tap a list item but how do I get without using the tap.
                           }
                       }

                    });
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: What is "the" record? Your list might have many, I don't see how the button is associated with one of them.

Comment: The toggle button is associated with every item/record in the list. So if I have 10 items in the list I have 10 toggle field

Comment: Could you please show your itemTpl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be best for you to use an if condition in your itemTpl or just get the value decided from a function. So, it will be like this:

```
var itemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for = ".">',
     '<div>{name}</div>',
     '<div class= "subSectionToggleButton">{active:this.setToggled}</div>',    
     '</tpl>',
     setToggled : function(active){
        if(active == true){             //Check the condition here
            return '<div class="active">Active</div>';
        }
        return '<div class="inactive">Inctive</div>';
     }
```

Or, you can just use a tpl if condition like this:

```
 var itemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for = ".">',
     '<div>{name}</div>',
     '<tpl if="active==true">',   // Or '<tpl if="active==\'true\'">',
         '<div class= "subSectionToggleButton">Active</div>', 
     '</tpl>',   
     '<tpl if="active==false">',
         '<div class= "subSectionToggleButton">Inactive</div>', 
     '</tpl>',
     '</tpl>');
```

Answer (score 0):

For your given scenario try to pass `HTMLElement` instead of `Ext.Element` to `getRecord` method

```
var rec = Ext.getCmp('sList').getRecord(f.getEl().dom);
```

Also you can get access to the list's records through `list.store.findRecord`
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/source/Store.html#Ext-data-Store-method-findRecord

Comment: Nah this doesn't work but I want this stuff to work as you mentioned, that would be a cleaner way to implement it.